# Compression series javascript files

Tags: javascript, node.js

People tell me the name of the package or module that will perform the following tasks. There are several js files for example:

```
/example/jquer.js
/library/modal.js и т.д.
```

I want these files are automatically created their compressed versions:

```
/example/jquer_min.js
/library/modal_min.js
```

Which may suggest tools to solution of this problem? Thank you!

Comment: webpack will do it for you!!

Answer (score 0):

try to use the following tools 
1- YUI Compressor
2- Google Closure Compiler
3- JSMin